# assign variable in while statement python

Tags: python, while-loop

Hi i'm trying to get a set of points from matplotlib.pyplot.ginput.
my idea is to save points in a list while the `actuaPoint!=lastPoint`

is there a way to do it something like:

```
lastPoint = None
pointList = []

actualPoint = plt.ginput(1)
while (actualPoint=plt.input()) != lastPoint:
    pointList.append(actualPoint)
    lastPoint= actualPoint
```

? resuming i'm trying to know if there's a way to do the variable assignment inside the while statement

Comment: Replace = with := in your while statement.

Comment: Important to mention that `:=` operator works only in python 3.9+ !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an assignment *expression*, using the `:=` operator.

```
point, = pointList = [plt.ginput(1)]
while (next_point := plt.input()) != point:
    pointList.append(next_point)
    point = next_point
```

Comment: This was exactly was I was looking for! many thanks! worked like charm! Also im gonna edit my post i wanted to user `plt.ginput` not input. If you could modify yours to match would be perfect

Comment: That actually makes it a little nicer, as I was struggling to find a cleaner way to avoid the duplicate call to `plt.input`.